# Distorted RTL text only in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with a Persian (an RTL language) text inside like this:

```
<div class="fullscreenMessage">در حال بازگردادن شما به حالت تمام صفحه</div>
```

Here is the wired and distorted result in chrome:

[image]

And Here is the normal result in Firefox:

[image]

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Note: I get no errors in console. I'm testing this locally in my laptop but in some servers I get the correct result even in chrome in others I get the same distorted result. Totally confused?!

Comment: That is sounding like a bug with chrome. I don't suppose you use any browser extensions?

Comment: Can you show your <meta> tags? Do you use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> fixed the issue please provide an answer.. @ Kosem

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` of your document.
This may work now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding issue, not an error that will be shown in the console.

Comment: encoding is auto-detected in the last version that I'm using...

Comment: What is the page encoding?